# Google Translate translates inline Javascript Code

Tags: php, javascript, curl, translation

I have some PHP code that sends a section of html code including some inline Javascript code by curl to google. When i get it back from Google translated into the language that i chose, the Javascript code has been translated too.

Any ideas as to how i can stop Google translating my inline JavaScript code? 
Thanks,
M

Answer (score 4):

Don't use inline JavaScript code at all...

Comment: I have no choice as it is littered through all of my customers site

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't really send any code, whether its HTML or Javascript, to a language translator.  I suggest translating it before encapsulating it in HTML or parsing it out of the HTML before translating.